# How to download Facebook sticker as .png or .jpg extention?

Tags: browser, download, facebook

I want to collect Facebook stickers as .png or .jpg files. If anyone already has them, please share with me. Or, is there a way to download them? Currently, I have a workaround solution to download one by one stickers that I send a sticker to someone in chat box, then right-click > Inspect Element > Find link of the sticker > View it in the new page > save it as .jpg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer myself, which access to http://facebookstickers.info/bun/, download a sticker that I need. Then use photoshop to cut them into seperate icons

Answer (score 4):

There's a tool doing the job: https://github.com/BirkhoffLee/facebook_sticker_extract.

It's written in Python and super fast, different extract size options available.